# How to write XPATH for nodes under dynamic hierarchy

Tags: xpath

I got a big XML. A snippet of that XML look like this:

```
<div class="x-column-inner" id="ext-gen422" style="width: 850px;">
 <div id="ext-comp-1206" style="width: 14px;" class=" x-column">
  <div tabindex="-1" class="x-form-item  x-hide-label" id="ext-gen434">
   <label class="x-form-item-label" style="width:100px;" for="ext-comp-1180" id="ext-gen435"></label>
  <div style="padding-left:105px" id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1180" class="x-form-element">
   <div class="x-form-check-wrap" id="ext-gen436" style="width: 14px; height: 28px;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ext-comp-1180" id="ext-comp-1180" autocomplete="off" class=" x-form-checkbox x-form-field">
     <label class="x-form-cb-label" for="ext-comp-1180" id="ext-gen437">&nbsp;</label>
    </div></div>  <div class="x-form-clear-left">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div id="ext-comp-1207" style="width: 150px;" class=" x-column">
  <label id="ext-comp-1203" style="width: 140px;">Add to Watchlist</label>
</div>
<div id="ext-comp-1208" style="width: 107px;" class=" x-column">
```

I need to find 'input' node of checkbox type based on label node having text 'Add to Watchlist'.

As both 'input' and 'label' node lies in different hierarchy, // syntax doesn't seem to work:

```
//div[label[contains(text(),'Add to Watchlist')]]
```

will just give parent div of child label. 
I tried to start from the topmost node of this snippet

```
$x("//div[@class='x-column-inner' and //label[contains(text(),'Add to Watchlist')]]")
```

but that is giving 6 possible matches.

Note: @id attribute can't be used as this is getting assigned dynamically to nodes so next time page loads @id will be different.
I don't want to use position() predicate as that makes XPATH static and xpath may break with any change in position.

Comment: What are the possible relations between your input and label tag in yout document? Also, do you want to retrieves the label or the input tags?

Comment: There seems to only logical relation as label is the label for input. i couldn't decipher syntactic relation :(

Comment: Discounting you example being malformed, they would appear to be siblings, so there's something you are not telling us.

Comment: Apologies for the bad indent. I've corrected it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, but it looks very greedy... Basically what it does is searching in every axes of the `input` tags to see if there is an associated `label` tag. So for each `input` it searches in its ancestors, descendants and siblings.
There are certainly some smarter solutions.

```
//input[@type = 'checkbox' and (@id = ancestor::label/@for or @id = descendant::label/@for or @id = following::label/@for or @id = preceding::label/@for)]
```

However your snippet is not interesting no `input` tag will be matched, please consider providing a better snippet. It would improve the answers accuracy.

**Edit** : Here is a (non-tested) way to add  the 'Add to Watchlist' constraint.

```
//input[@type = 'checkbox' and (@id = ancestor::label[. = 'Add to Watchlist']/@for or @id = descendant::label[. = 'Add to Watchlist']/@for or @id = following::label[. = 'Add to Watchlist']/@for or @id = preceding::label[. = 'Add to Watchlist']/@for)]
```

But once again, those xpath requests are very greedy and your are not guaranteed to match every `input` element associated to a `label` for example the following `input` won't be match in this snippet:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="id">Add to Watchlist</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="id" />
  </div>
<div>
```

There may be more efficient solutions in one xpath request, but you should consider doing several request.
For example, one request to find every `for` attribute value of the `label` elements with the text 'Add to Watchlist' and then doing another request to find the associated `input` elements.
I should also try to restrict your request to the scope a the underlying `form` element. Perhaps I will edit with a better request if I find the time.

**Edit 2**
Here is a working and smarter request

```
//form//input[@type = 'checkbox' and @id = ancestor::form[1]//label[. = 'Add to Watchlist']/@for]
```

You can confront it to this snippet

```
<html>
  <form>
    <label for="bar">Add to Watchlist</label>
    <div>
      <div>
        <label for="id">Add to Watchlist</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="id" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="foo" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="bar" />
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <label for="foo">Add to Watchlist</label>
</html>
```

Bust the most important is that you understand how it works and why it is better. Please take the time to think about it.

Comment: Please pardon my snippet. Would giving larger snippet, that is superset of this snippet, would make it better? I didn't add too big snippet as it would have made question clumsy. Any other idea to make it better snippet for improving answers accuracy? Thanks.

Comment: You shoud create a minimalistic snippet where some `input` nodes will be matched by the xpath expression. Have you tried my answer?

Comment: Thanks Zoom. Your solution has narrowed down nodes to the two checkboxes present in xml. 2 nodes being:
`<input type="checkbox" name="ext-comp-1185" id="ext-comp-1185" autocomplete="off" class=" x-form-checkbox x-form-field">`
`<input type="checkbox" name="ext-comp-1180" id="ext-comp-1180" autocomplete="off" class=" x-form-checkbox x-form-field">`
Now as both the nodes doesn't have any unique attribute, except dynamic @id, do i need to resort to position()?

Comment: I don't understand what you need to achieve. The two `input` tag found have been selected because they are linked to another `label` tag with a `for` attribute that match the `id` attribute of the `input` tag. Is it what you want?

Comment: thanks for your time and help. Actually I wanted only `input` node that is attached to specific `label` having text `Add to Watchlist` so I modified xpath to: 
`//input[@type = 'checkbox' and (@id = ancestor::label/@for or @id = descendant::label/@for or @id = following-sibling::label/@for or @id = preceding-sibling::label/@for) and (following::label = 'Add to Watchlist')]` 
and it worked :)

Comment: Though I’ve one doubt: the xpath that you’ve written searches for associated `for` attribute in `label` node but the xml that I provided that doesn’t have any `@for` attribute in the node `<label id="ext-comp-1203" style="width: 140px;">Add to Watchlist</label>` then how did we manage to get right `input` tag. Is there anything am missing? Thanks.

Comment: If there is no `for` attribute to the `label` element, then the `label` is not associated to any `input` element. This is a mandatory prerequisite. Either your it the way you manipulate extjs or an extjs bug I can't tell you.
As for the request you post above that is not the way to do it. I will update my answer.